# Matlab - Read An Unknown CSV

Tags: matlab, csv

How can i read (convert to a cell of strings) a CSV file with an unknown column structure (number, datatypes), but standard compliant?

In particular, having numbers, strings, dates, etc. comma delimited, and optional double quoted strings.

The `textscan` function requires to know the format string `'%s...%s'` which is variable, and the `csvread` function only works for numeric arrays.

Sample File, in this case, with 4 columns.

```
header1,header2,header3,header4
a,"2017-11-04T00:00:00",,remark1,10.1
b,"2017-11-05T00:00:00",,remarkb,10.2
c,"2017-11-06T00:00:00",,remarkc,10.3
d,"2017-11-07T00:00:00",2017-11-07T00:06:00,"remarkd1,remarkd2",10.5
```

Comment: Can you post a sample of your file?

Comment: Also possibly explain a bit better what is unknown about this file and what is known. You may be able to do it by reading the file line by line into a cell.